# How to get ImageButton size within Android GridView?

Tags: android, layout, graphics

I'm subclassing ImageButton in order to draw lines on it and trying to figure out where the actual button coordinates are within my gridview. I am using onGlobalLayout to setup Top, Bottom, Right and Left, but these seem to be for the actual "square" within the grid, and not the actual button (see image). The purple lines are drawn in myImageButton.onDraw() using coords gathered from myImageButton.onGlobalLayout(). I thought these would be for the button, but they seem to be from something else. Not sure what. I'd like the purple lines to match the outline of the button so the lines I draw appear on the button and not just floating out in the LinearLayout somewhere. The light blue is the background color of the vertical LinearLayout holding the Textview (for the number) and myImageButton. Any way to get the actual button size?

[image: gridview/layout/button]

XML Layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lay_cellframe"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_cell"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <com.example.icaltest2.myImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@android:color/transparent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

myImageButton.java

```
   public myImageButton (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
   {
       super (context, attrs);
       mBounds = new Rect();
       ViewTreeObserver vto = this.getViewTreeObserver ();
       vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener (ogl);
       Log.d (TAG, "myImageButton");
   }


...

    OnGlobalLayoutListener ogl = new OnGlobalLayoutListener()
        {


            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout ()
            {
                Rect b = getDrawable ().getBounds ();


                mBtnTop = b.centerY () - (b.height () / 2);
                mBtnBot = b.centerY () + (b.height () / 2);
                mBtnLeft = b.centerX () - (b.width () / 2);
                mBtnRight = b.centerX () + (b.width () / 2);

            }
        };
...

 @Override
   protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas)
   {

      super.onDraw (canvas);
      Paint p = new Paint ();
        p.setStyle (Paint.Style.STROKE);
        p.setStrokeWidth (1);

        p.setColor (Color.MAGENTA);
        canvas.drawCircle (mBtnLeft, mBtnTop, 2, p);
        canvas.drawCircle (mBtnLeft, mBtnBot, 2, p);
        canvas.drawCircle (mBtnRight, mBtnTop, 2, p);
        canvas.drawCircle (mBtnRight, mBtnBot, 2, p);
            canvas.drawRect (mBtnLeft, mBtnTop, mBtnRight, mBtnBot, p);


}
```

**Update:** added image with jsmith's suggestion

```
Rect r = canvas.getClipBounds (); //<- not sure about this
        int w = getMeasuredWidth () - getPaddingLeft () - getPaddingRight ();
        int h = getMeasuredHeight () - getPaddingTop () - getPaddingBottom ();

        int left = r.centerX () - (w / 2);
        int right = r.centerX() + ( w / 2);
        int top = r.centerY() - (h / 2);
        int bot = r.centerY() + (h / 2);


        p.setColor (Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawRect (left, top, right, bot, p);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time onDraw is called the layout was handled and the size information should be available.  You can use the `View.getMeasuredWidth() / View.getMeasuredHeight()` to retrieve the information that you need.  However, you may also need to factor in the padding with `View.getPaddingLeft() / ..`.  For example:

```
final int displayWidth = (getMeasuredWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight());
```

Comment: Hmm.. Seems to be about the same result as the purple rectangle (new image uploaded above).

Comment: Can you describe where you want to draw the box with respect to the button?

Comment: Basically just a bounding box which represents the area the button widget takes up regardless of screen dpi (scaling, etc. -- needs to work with both tablets and phones). I would prefer not to have to do any 'fudging' for 9-patch padding. It seems that getClipBounds() returns the correct numbers but since there is a transparent 2,3,5 pixel border, it's not exactly over the button. Perhaps I should try adding a transparent image to the button which Android will place inside the widget properly? Then use the transparent image coords instead? Hmm..

Comment: I ended up using a transparent "Src" png image and setting up a selector file for the Background (to animate a button press). The selector file didn't have any included padding (like a 9-patch) so it came out to the edges of the bounds.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're doing is right, the problem is Android's standard button style has about 3dip of padding, so it seems the image is aligning to the gridview's cell, but is not.

So, the lines will need to have less 6dip width (3 to left and 3 to right) to fit the button's view.

```
mBtnLeft = b.centerX () - (b.width () / 2) + 3;
mBtnRight = b.centerX () + (b.width () / 2) - 3;
```

Comment: True, the 9-patch images used for the widgets do indeed have some 'built in' padding, however the difference seems to be more than the 3 pixels so not sure if it's a multiple of the scale factor applied to the widget, or if I should be doing this differently.